# postgresql capistrano - resulting database.yml is wrong

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, capistrano3

I have created a rails application and now I am trying to deploy it using capistrano. I have the following in my deploy.rb, as said by the creators of capistrano/postgres

```
set :pg_database, "BusAlert_production"
set :pg_user, "BusAlert_production"
set :pg_ask_for_password, true
```

when I run cap production setup - the Cli requires me to enter a password for the database and user, and it seems to work fine.

but when I run cap production deploy - I get the following error:

> PG::Error: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user
>   "BusAlertServer_production"

which is odd as the configuration clearly states BusAlert_production, not BusAlertServer_production (this entire thing is done, because of previous errors when not setting database and user)

so I decided to check the resulting database.yml in my remote machine - and I have the following

```
production:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: BusAlertServer_production
  pool: 5
  username: BusAlertServer_production
  password: '15af025e203334a3895a'
  host: localhost
```

besides the fact that this is not the password I entered, BusAlertServer_production doesn't event exist. can any one tell me why is capistrano using the default postgres configuration in the deploy task, and not mine?

Comment: Can you check the permissions on your database.yml file? `chmod ugo+rwx database.yml` just to make sure?

Comment: Also, I used capistrano before and I absolutely hated it. If you are trying to deploy to Amazon consider using ElasticBeanstalk

Comment: I am not sure how changing the permissions on my remote database.yml will fix the fact that it is wrong. Any way, I am not sure if I want to learn some thing new from scratch, but Will ElasticBeanstalk work for an azure VM?

Comment: I'm not sure if it will work with Azure but ElasticBeanstalk is as easy as Heroku to get ROR app deployed. It also automatically configures your autoscaling, load balancing for you

Comment: Also maybe I'm not understanding your question, but it seems like your local database.yml is not being copied over to remote via the FTP of capistrano? So that is why I suggested the permissions thing.

Comment: I'm not sure. But maybe this file exist in repo and deploy server don't have 'db' role?